# Remove lines ending with "0." after lines ending with "0."

Tags: regex, bash, grep, multiline

I'm looking for a way to remove via bash a multilines pattern from a very large txt file.

I have lines like this ones:

```
    1;alias;1.872198312
    2;alias;0.
    3;alias;0.
    4;alias;2.982193126
    5;alias;1.987502017
    6;alias;0.
    7;alias;0.802829100
    8;alias;0.
    9;alias;0.
    10;alias;0.
    11;alias;0.
    12;alias;1.7210172
```

I would like to transform this file into something like:

```
    1;alias;1.872198312
    2;alias;0.
    4;alias;2.982193126
    5;alias;1.987502017
    6;alias;0.
    7;alias;0.802829100
    8;alias;0.
    12;alias;1.7210172
```

hence reducing the size of the file.

I have tried a grep approach:

```
    grep '0.$^[a-zA-Z0-9.;_]0.$' file.txt
```

with no success.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by using `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '{if ($NF == "0.") if (!z) z=1; else next; else z=0} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
1;alias;1.872198312
2;alias;0.
4;alias;2.982193126
5;alias;1.987502017
6;alias;0.
7;alias;0.802829100
8;alias;0.
12;alias;1.7210172
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I try to run this command I simply get a blank output. maybe something's messing about text coding.

Comment: ok try this command: `awk -F';' '{if ($NF+0 == 0) if (!z) z=1; else next; else z=0} 1' file`

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but it's still not working... It selects only come lines.

Comment: [See this working demo of above code](http://ideone.com/GDCRYY) It seems your actual input is different from the sample provided in question.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
$ sed '/0\.$/{:a;N;/0\.$/s/\n.*$//;ta}' infile
    1;alias;1.872198312
    2;alias;0.
    4;alias;2.982193126
    5;alias;1.987502017
    6;alias;0.
    7;alias;0.802829100
    8;alias;0.
    12;alias;1.7210172
```

Commented:

```
/0\.$/ {              # If a line ends with '0.'
    :a                # Label to branch to
    N                 # Append next line to pattern space
    /0\.$/s/\n.*$//   # If that next line ends with '0.', remove it
    ta                # If we made a substitution, branch to label
}
```

To use the one-liner with BSD sed, there has to be an extra `;` after the `ta`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I can't get it to work.
        sed: 1: "/0\.$/{:a;N;/0\.$/s/\n. ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: @jetstream Also with the extra `;` inserted after `ta`? What about when you put commands on new lines each, as in the commented example, maybe without the comments and without indentation? It works here as a one-liner, also in POSIX compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'print if ! ($skipnext = /;0\.$/) || ! $skip; $skip = $skipnext;' input
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line.
- `/;0\.$/` is a regex. It matches a semicolon, zero, dot, end of line.
- `!` is negation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It actually works in a test file, but I cannot manage to get it work on the original (1.5GB) file: there it keeps multiple "0." ending lines.
EDIT: it seems like it has problems dealing with files that large... I keep trying.

Comment: The file size is irrelevant. Maybe there are spaces after the `0.`?

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not sure about that. How may I take possible spaces in account? e.g. 0.______$

Comment: `/;0\.\s*$/` maybe? `\s` matches any whitespace.

Comment: It still doesn't work, but, if I split the file it works like a charm... Might a buffering issue be there?

Comment: It reads the file line by line, and only keeps one line in memory.